# Error in the build of project with gradle from Hudson and its deployment in artifactory

Tags: hudson, gradle, artifactory

I just added the hudson-artifactory plugin, and everything run  marvelously with Maven, but when I tried to build the project with gradle (I added the gradle plugin to hudson)

I got this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception. * Where: Initialization
>   script 'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\qqqqqqqqqqqq.hudson\jobs\skiiiiiiiiiin\builds\2010-08-10_10-45-03\init-artifactory.gradle'
>   line: 2 * What went wrong: A problem
>   occurred evaluating initialization
>   script. Cause: No signature of method:
>   org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.apply()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (init_artifactory_gradle_bb54a6ea5f854f8feae8c6181e5acbf4$_run_closure1_closure2)
>   values:
>   [init_artifactory_gradle_bb54a6ea5f854f8feae8c6181e5acbf4$_run_closure1_closure2@1d7b222]
>   * Try: Run with -s or -d option to get more details. Run with -S option to
>   get the full (very verbose)
>   stacktrace. BUILD FAILED Total time:
>   1.942 secs Finished: FAILURE

Comment: `Try: Run with -s or -d option to get more details. Run with -S option to get the full (very verbose) stacktrace.` If you hae still questions than, post the results.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin requires Gradle 0.9-preview-3+
Try using the latest version.

Comment: we must add    http://gradle.artifactoryonline.com/gradle/libs/  and http://gradle.artifactoryonline.com/gradle/plugins/  on remote repository :))   and everything works !

Answer (score 1):

we must add gradle.artifactoryonline.com/gradle/libs and gradle.artifactoryonline.com/gradle/plugins on remote repository :)) and everything works !